# Java LDAP get Group DN by using CN

Tags: java, java-8, ldap, ldap-query

I want to get Group DN by using CN. For this I am using below code.

```
public static String getGroupDNByCN(DirContext ctx, String cn) {
    String groupDN = "";
    String searchFilter = "(&(objectClass=group)(cn=groupCN))";
    try {
        SearchControls searchControls = new SearchControls();
        searchControls.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE);
        NamingEnumeration<SearchResult> resultsGrp = ctx.search("ou=groups,o=data", searchFilter, searchControls);
        while (resultsGrp.hasMoreElements()) {
            SearchResult result = (SearchResult) resultsGrp.next();
            Attributes attrs = result.getAttributes();
            System.out.println("attrs : " + attrs);
            groupDN = attrs.get("distinguishedName").get().toString();
            resultsGrp.nextElement();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception : " + e);
    }

    return groupDN;
}
```

When I run this I am getting the below values in `attrs` that I did `sysout`

```
{owner=owner: cn=admin,ou=sa,o=system, equivalenttome=equivalentToMe: cn=ksuchostawski,ou=users,o=data, cn=lsazonova,ou=users,o=data, cn=lsazonovatest,ou=users,o=data, cn=mnewuser,ou=users,o=data, cn=mwu,ou=users,o=data, cn=nuser,ou=users,o=data, cn=rdevenyi,ou=users,o=data, cn=sbudan,ou=users,o=data, cn=sbudan1,ou=users,o=data, cn=sbudan2,ou=users,o=data, cn=sbudan21,ou=users,o=data, cn=staylor,ou=users,o=data, cn=stest,ou=users,o=data, cn=suser,ou=users,o=data, cn=cgrugina,ou=users,o=data, cn=crugina,ou=users,o=data, cn=ddev1,ou=users,o=data, cn=dpro1,ou=users,o=data, cn=dpro2,ou=users,o=data, cn=dpro21,ou=users,o=data, cn=dpro4,ou=users,o=data, cn=dpro5,ou=users,o=data, objectclass=objectClass: groupOfNames, Top, acl=ACL: 2#entry#[Root]#member, cn=cn: pcvc, member=member: cn=ksuchostawski,ou=users,o=data, cn=lsazonova,ou=users,o=data, cn=lsazonovatest,ou=users,o=data, cn=mnewuser,ou=users,o=data, cn=mwu,ou=users,o=data, cn=nuser,ou=users,o=data, cn=rdevenyi,ou=users,o=data, cn=sbudan,ou=users,o=data, cn=sbudan1,ou=users,o=data, cn=sbudan2,ou=users,o=data, cn=sbudan21,ou=users,o=data, cn=staylor,ou=users,o=data, cn=stest,ou=users,o=data, cn=suser,ou=users,o=data, cn=cgrugina,ou=users,o=data, cn=crugina,ou=users,o=data, cn=ddev1,ou=users,o=data, cn=dpro1,ou=users,o=data, cn=dpro2,ou=users,o=data, cn=dpro21,ou=users,o=data, cn=dpro4,ou=users,o=data, cn=dpro5,ou=users,o=data}
```

In the above `Attributes` there is no `distinguishedName` attribute. Please help me how can I get Group DN by using CN.

I am using `Java` and `NetIQ eDirectory 8.8 SP8 v20810.20`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the getNameInNamespace() method for JNDI.

SO like:

```
groupDN = result.getNameInNamespace();
```

-jim